# How to get sed to replace a UTF-8 character?

Tags: bash, shell, utf-8, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
   echo "EXECUTING SCRIPT"
 #if found
   if head -3 file.txt | grep "\* something";then
   echo found something
   sed -i -e "/^ \* something/ s/ Copyright old/ \xc2\xa9 Copyright new/"  file.txt
```

> copyright symbol is being displayed as xc2xa9

```
 #if not found
   else
   echo something not found
   echo -e "/**\n** \xc2\xa9 Copyright new\n**/" | cat - file.txt > temp.txt 
fi
```

> copyright symbol worked fine here

Please let me know how to get the symbol using `sed` command.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. What version of sed are you using? (What does `sed --version` print?)

Comment: It's printing: This is not GNU sed version 4.0

Comment: That's an intriguing response.  Are you using Busybox or something similar?  What platform are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-e` option for `sed` is unrelated to the `-e` option for `echo`, so it is not very surprising that you get different results.  A lot depends on your shell, too, since the shell processes the double-quoted argument to `sed` before `sed` gets to see it.  Given that you are having problems one way and not the other, the obvious workaround is:

```
sed -i -e "/^ \* something/ s/ Copyright old/ $(echo -e "\xc2\xa9") Copyright new/" file.txt
```

That captures the output of the relevant part of the working `echo -e` notation and embeds it in the replacement text.